# How to loop over nested JSON arrays, get values and then modify them based off index in shell using JQ

Tags: json, shell, jq, zsh

this is the JSON I am working with -

```json
{
  "content": {
    "macOS": {
      "releases": [
        {
          "version": "3.21",
          "updateItems": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "Automatic detection for inactivity is here",
              "message": "We've finally added a feature long requested - Orby now detects when you've been inactive on your computer.  You can modify the maximum allowable inactive time through settings, or just turn it off if you don't need it",
              "image": "https://static.image.png"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "In case you missed it... We have an iOS app  ",
              "message": "It's far from perfect, but it's come a long way since we first pushed out version 1.0.  We don't that many users on it so far, but I'm hoping that it's useful.  Please send any feedback and feature requests my way",
              "image": "https://static.image.png"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "iOS": {
      "releases": [
        {
          "version": "1.31",
          "updateItems": [
            {
              "image": "https://static.image.png",
              "id": 1,
              "link": "orbit://com.orbit:/settings",
              "message": "Strict mode offers a fantastic new way to keep your focus and get more done.  To enable it, go to settings and toggle it on.  Now when you want to run a timer, put your device face down on a surface.  The timer will stop if you pick it up.",
              "title": "Strict mode is here  ⚠️ ⚠️ ⚠️"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to translate all the title values and message values (I use shell translate).

In my attempt, I have looped through the `releases`, gotten the indices, then looped through the `updateItems` and gotten their indices, then translated the `title` and `message` based off both these indices, and then I've attempted to assign these new values to replace the existing `title` and `message`.

I've noticed that this results in all the title values being the same, and all the message values being the same.

I'm clearly using `jq` the wrong way, but am unsure how to correct.

Please help.

```bash
curl ${URL} | jq >englishContent.json

LANGUAGES=(
    # "en"
    # "de"
    # "fr"
    # "es"
    "it"
    # "ja"
    # "ko"
    # "nl"
    # "pt-BR"
    # "ru"
    # "zh-Hans"
)

for language in $LANGUAGES; do

    # Create new json payload from the downloaded english content json
    result=$(jq '{ "language": "'$language'", "response": . }' englishContent.json)

    # Get the total number of release items
    macOS_releases_length=$(jq -r ".response.content.macOS.releases | length" <(echo "$result"))

    # Iterate over releases items and then use index to substitute values into nested arrays
    macOS_releases_length=$(expr "$macOS_releases_length" - 1)
    for macOS_release_index in $(seq 0 $macOS_releases_length); do

        update_items_length=$(jq ".response.content.macOS.releases[$macOS_release_index].updateItems | length" <(echo "$result"))

        update_items_length=$(expr "$update_items_length" - 1)
        for update_item_index in $(seq 0 $update_items_length); do

            title=$(jq ".response.content.macOS.releases[$macOS_release_index].updateItems[$update_item_index].title" <(echo "$result"))
            translated_title=$(trans -brief -no-warn :$language $title | xargs)

            message=$(jq ".response.content.macOS.releases[$macOS_release_index].updateItems[$update_item_index].message" <(echo "$result"))
            translated_message=$(trans -brief -no-warn :$language $message | xargs)
            
            result=$(jq --arg release_index "$(echo "$macOS_release_index" | jq 'tonumber')" --arg item_index "$("$update_item_index" | jq 'tonumber')" --arg new_title $translated_title '.response.content.macOS.releases['$release_index'].updateItems['$item_index'].title |= $new_title' <(echo "$result"))
            result=$(jq --arg release_index "$(echo "$macOS_release_index" | jq 'tonumber')" --arg item_index "$("$update_item_index" | jq 'tonumber')" --arg new_message $translated_message '.response.content.macOS.releases['$release_index'].updateItems['$item_index'].message |= $new_message' <(echo "$result"))
        done
    done
    echo $result
done
```

Comment: Try double-quoting the `"$translated_title"` and the `"$translated_message"` variables in the `--arg new_title $translated_title` and `--arg new_message $translated_message` final jq JSON manipulations.

Comment: Also, your question is tagged with both `zsh` and `bash`.  Which shell are you utilizing?  (I added a `#~/bin/zsh` shebang to your script when testing locally.)

Comment: Oh sorry, it’s zsh.  I’ll update that

Comment: also sorry, double quoting doesn't seem to change anything.